# Jquery get the key/value - key from asp drop down

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have the following in my code:

```
    <asp:DropDownList id="City" runat="server">
```

I tried using the following to get the key from the key value but it shows up as undefined although I selected  from the dropdown

```
    var city = $("#city option:selected").val();

    alert(city);
```

Comment: You just need `$('#City').val()` to get the selected options value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should simply use the `.val()` method on the `select` element itself, rather than searching for the `option:selected` child (as you're currently doing). `ID`s in CSS are also case-sensitive.

```
var city = $("#City").val();
alert(city);
```

Answer (score 0):

The cases don't match between the ID and the selector.

```
var city=$("#City option:selected").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by key and value, but I'm assuming you mean the text and value of the selected option. Try something like this:

```
var selectedOption = $("#<%= City.ClientID %> option:selected");
if (selectedOption){
    alert($(selectedOption).text() + "/" + $(selectedOption).val());
}
```